# Proper way to load a single post via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, single

I'm loading single posts via Ajax into a div that I have set up on my index page. Everything is working fine in this regard. I want to use history.js to push/pop the state so if users enter `example.com/my-post` into the address bar, it loads up the index page with the post already loaded in the div. That is where the problem lies.

**This is a simplified version of the function I'm using (the actual also includes a slide):**

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $args = array(
        'p' => $_POST['post_id'],
        'post_type' => 'projects'
        );

    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post-container">
        <div id="project-content">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .post-container -->

    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_die();
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
```

**This is how I'm calling it:**

```
$('.post-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).data('id'), // data-id attribute for .post-link
        projectTitle = $(this).data('title'), // data-title attribute for .post-link
        projectSlug = $(this).data('slug'), // data-slug attribute for .post-link
        ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl; // Ajax URL localized from functions.php

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        context: this,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-container').html(response);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the loop**

```
<?php $home_query = new WP_Query('post_type=projects');

while($home_query->have_posts()) : $home_query->the_post(); ?>

    <article class="project">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'home-thumb' ); ?>
        <div class="overlay">
            <a class="post-link expand" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-slug="<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>">+</a>
        </div>
    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way. I'm confused and a part of me is thinking that I should put all the html into my `single` template and call that from the Ajax function. But then I don't exactly know how that would work either because if the user enters `example.com/my-post` into their browser, it'll only load the single post without all of the html on the index page. I hope I'm explaining this correctly. Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: but, why do you need this? i mean, what could be the reason for loading your content using ajax instead of just showing data inside single.php? You dont know that must search engines wont see the content at all?!

Comment: @SagiveSEO Well, [this site](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#partitura) is similar to what I had in mind. See how that page loads with the project already in the div? I noticed that in the [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=reveal+partitura), it leads to the `single` template, which is fine with me.

Comment: I dont understand... (Sorry). what do you "project already in the div" do you mean this effect? https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/ ??

Comment: @SagiveSEO Oh, no not that effect. Sorry if I wasn't clear. When you click [this link](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#partitura), it opens with the "Partitura" project loaded in the div. The home page [just opens without any projects loaded.](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/)

Comment: @SagiveSEO It's the area highlighted in red here: http://i.imgur.com/md0a1Ul.jpg

Comment: yee, got that after checking out the theme in a more in depth fashion... this does not matter the code i gave you. you just need to retrieve the desired to return. meaning the image, video / etc... the excerpt, title and so on.

Comment: my js code works on page load. You need to wrap with jquery and not document.ready and then listen to a click from a button that gives the post id and then return the data as replay. see revision 2

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my view:** Load it inside your single.php why use ajax at all? 
Google wont be able to see this (using most crawlers).

In any case - here is the right way to return the data...
please note that you can use get_post or wp_query. up tp you.

**JS Part:**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
        action: 'my_load_ajax_content ',            
        post_id: post_id  // << should grab this from input...

    }, function(data) {

        var $response   =   $(data);
        var postdata    =   $response.filter('#postdata').html();

        $('.TARGETDIV').html(postdata);
    });
});
```

**PHP Part:**

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $pid        = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    $the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid));

    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $data = '
            <div class="post-container">
                <div id="project-content">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">'.get_the_title().'</h1>
                    <div class="entry-content">'.get_the_content().'</div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            ';

        }
    } 
    else {
        echo '<div id="postdata">'.__('Didnt find anything', THEME_NAME).'</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();


    echo '<div id="postdata">'.$data.'</div>';
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
```

Hope this helps.
again, i wouldnt recommend doing that but... this should work.

**REVISION FOR GET POST ON CLICK**

first: the button / link - should be something like

```
<button class="get_project" data-postid="POSTID HERE!">PROJECT NAME</button>
```

second: the js code listening to a click:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('.get_project').click(function() {

        var postid = $(this).attr('data-postid');

        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'my_load_ajax_content ',            
            postid: postid
        }, function(data) {
            var $response   =   $(data);
            var postdata    =   $response.filter('#postdata').html();
            $('.TARGETDIV').html(postdata);
        });

    })

});
```

The php code needs no changing - just set the data you need.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear in my question. I have no problem retrieving the post. I updated my post to show you the full Ajax call and also my WordPress loop. My problem is that when I refresh (or enter the project url directly into the browser i.e `example.com/post-title`, it doesn't load because that url does not exist. So how do I make it load with the project already loaded like [this page](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#partitura)?

Comment: sorry, I still dont understand. If your "single" custom post doesnt show up - maybe you forgot to create a single-projects.php page? when you click a link to a custom page that has the file that was meant to show that content - then... you should have no problem. This is not related at all to ajax...!

Comment: I do have a single page as well as a single-projects page but I don't need those because I'm building a one page site. The posts will only be on the home page so I want them to have the url like this: `example.com/title-of-post` instead of `example.com/projects/title-of-post`. I can redirect the latter to the former using `htaccess` but I'm not sure how I can make the post load using that url (`example.com/title-of-post`).

Comment: listen mate... it hard to understand what you really want. When you click the link - you dont want to go to another page? but your ajax works - so? what do you want? just to add a dash to the url?

Comment: No, I don't want it to go to another page. I want it to behave exactly like this page but without the hashtag in the URL: http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#partitura

Comment: but this is what the ajax does... so - which part are you missing? what doesnt work?

Comment: First off... there is a script loading before jQUery (dont know if its related) - i see tha ajax call but your url stil loads. Why not try my standard - working - tested ajax... You can also catch me on Skype and then i can have maybe a better look inside - my skype: sagive-seo