# Get custom post type's fields in a while loop as variables

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, variables

I'm working on a page that shows the name of a lot of products (custom post type), and when the user clicks on the name he can see some product information.  It's something like this:

- Main page with products list
- ---------Product info page.

Everything is working right now, but I don't know if I am doing in the proper way.

In my code I do a while loop to get the posts, and each post has a link to a generic product page, that gets the variables to show the specific data of the product via URL.

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>          

<a href="http://www.gador.com.ar/mvp-ficha/?nombre=<?php the_title(); ?>&principio=<?php the_excerpt();?>&info=<?php the_content();?>&accion=<?php the_field('accion_terapeutica'); ?>&presentacion=<?php the_field('presentaciones'); ?>&foto=<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>&prospecto=<?php the_field('prospecto'); ?>"  class="btn btn-raised cardio-dark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
} ?>
```

Then, in my product I get the info using a lot of

```
<?php echo $_GET["variable-name"] ?>
```

I am doing the page in this way because the product's custom post type template can't be changed (because it's used in a different section of the website), and I need to show the data in a specific style.

The problem with this solution is that, in some way, all the info of the products is already loaded in the while loop. Is there a more "elegant" way to do this? I think that I should only load the name in the main page, and get the product info after the user clics on the product, but I don't know how to do this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In order to gather more information, would you mind explaining why editing the custom post type template is not an option? What's its filename and where is it being called from? There is probably a solution that will allow you to use the main loop as usual without having to pass the variables through the url.

Comment: Hi Luis! 

The main wordpress installation was made by another team. In the main website the users can look at the products, etc, and also information like news, contact, etc.

Now, the company wants a side-website that only shows the products in a different style, and also a product info page in a different style (we are going to show the info in a modal, indeed). So: we can't change the template of the product, because the original template is used in the main website; we only need the info to show it in a modal.

Comment: I see. I understand that you have a different page template for showcasing all the products, but I'm not sure about the single product view. Is the modal loaded from the all-products page or first you go to the alternative single product page and the modal is loaded from there? Also, what are you loading inside the modal? A different WP instance (iframe), an ajax call, a javascript-only solution...? Sorry for asking so much!

Comment: Hi Luis, thank you for taking your time! I'm sory for not being very clear (and for my english too!).

The modal is loaded from the all-products page and it loads an iframe of my own version of single-product, and that single-product is the file that gets the variables via URL.

Comment: If the modal is not too complex, you can stick to a javascript-only solution. Otherwise, the "WordPress way" of doing that would be using [`wp_ajax_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) passing the ID as a parameter in the ajax call. You have several examples here on how to use it: [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174266/trying-to-get-single-posts-to-load-on-the-front-page-via-ajax) or [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41062/81084) and [another one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175869/81084).

Comment: Hi Luis, I've tried to do it like in the links you send me but I can't get it done. I'm even trying to do it without a modal, using just a regular div, but I think I'm missing something. I have added the function `my_load_ajax_content ()` as described in [this link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175865/proper-way-to-load-a-single-post-via-ajax/175869#175869). And I'm using the same JS  and button ´<button class="get_project" data-postid="POSTID HERE!">PROJECT NAME</button>´. I'm working on [this](http://www.gador.com.ar/mvp/). As you may see, Get project doesn't do anything yet

Comment: I think I'm getting closer using [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/04/01/loading-wordpress-posts-with-ajax-and-jquery/) :)